# Discerning a Production SessionId cookie from a Sandbox one

Tags: javascript, session, browser, session-id

I'm trying to explore the browser's cookies and identify the Production SessionId. The thing is when i retrieved all the cookies filtered by `sid`, which is how they're called, I recieved over 30 (sandboxes, and others).

The [cookie object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/Cookie) I'm exploring (from a web-ext) looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "sid",
    "value": "00D58000000JetR!AQsAQBHLV9WUr6v3ILmFTDwBoBppWjhtu6HJi1HzD31YtUhedQ.JVPh.3qRqFzmawXdNABRScAl1VJXuCAVzVTqeKRHv1z7D",
    "domain": "my-org.my.salesforce.com",
    "hostOnly": true,
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "session": true,
    "firstPartyDomain": "",
    "storeId": "firefox-default"
}
```

But as you can see, there is no valuable information in order to discern.

Are you aware of any hacks to sort them?

Comment: 1. 00D58000000JetR seems to be org id. 2. my-org.my seems to be org prefix. if that has double dash -- it can be a sandbox, f.e. my-org--cs12.dev

Comment: @kurunve worked for me. I did find an inconvenient when trying to discern between a production and a developer... but it makes sense. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)